# Array of data will auto generate Text Input of each object in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have an array of data looks like this.

```
  [
        {
          accountId: 1,
          name: 'Mike',
        },
        {
          accountId: 2,
          name: 'Mike',
        },
        {
          accountId: 3,
          name: 'Mike',
        },
        {
          accountId: 4,
          name: 'Mike',
        },
        {
          accountId: 5,
          name: 'Mike',
        },
        {
          accountId: 6,
          name: 'Mike',
        },
        {.....},
        {.....}
      ]
```

I want an auto generated Text input that handles each input.

Note: the array is not fix number of data, there's a 1 - 50 or its defends on each account.

sample code, I do the lodash map to render the array and call the _handleMultiInput so I can easily manipulate the data.

```
{_.map(this.state.selectedAccounts, (data, index) => {
            const indexPlus = index + 1;
            return (
              <Row style={{ paddingBottom: 25 }}>
                <Col>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{data.accoundId}</Text>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{data.name}</Text>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <Item
                    regular
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: '#FFFFF',
                      borderRadius: 6,
                      borderColor: 'lightgray',
                    }}>
                    <Input
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      placeholderTextColor="lightgray"
                      keyboardType="numeric"
                      onChangeText={this._handleMultiInput('amount', indexPlus)}
                    />
                    {/* <Icon name='person' style={{ color: 'lightgray' }} /> */}
                  </Item>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            );
          })}
```

sample function for Input

```
 _handleMultiInput(name, indexPlus) {
    return text => {
      this.setState({ [name + indexPlus]: text });
      let _state = 'amount' + indexPlus;
      console.log(_state);
      console.log(this.state[_state]); // it work !
      // this.setState({
      //   setOfAmountValue: this.state[_newValue]
      // })
      console.log([...this.state.amount[`${indexPlus}`]]);
      console.log(this.state.setOfAmountValue);
    };
  }
```

You can see my whole code here a [RN test](https://snack.expo.io/@mrvictoria/rn-test)

Comment: but what is your question? You can create a "post" with question and answer, but I didn't find the question.

Comment: Hi @JoaoPolo I want to have an auto generated text input that handles each object, users input.

Answer (score 2):

```
value={this.state['amount' + indexPlus] != undefined ?this.state['amount' + indexPlus] : "" }
```

Add this line to your TextInput props. And remove this one :

```
  console.log([...this.state.amount[`${indexPlus}`]]);
```

Comment: hmmm my next question is how can I insert in setOfAmountValue each this.state['amount' + indexPlus] ?

Comment: I suggest you to add a key to your selectedAccounts object named inputValue. You don't need to define another array for this. I changed your snack.expo code. Check it out. https://snack.expo.io/B1BPkcy7I